# How do I get an alert to pop up when a text box is full in a pdf form?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am making a fillable pdf with a text box with a maximum 3000 characters. is there a way to have an alert pop up if someone continues to type when the text box is full?  I'm totally new to javascript and am feeling a bit overwhelmed with all the information online :(

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Please post examples of the code you have tried using so far.

Also look at this: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJSGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JavaScript at all. Simply open the field properties and in the Option tab set the maximum number of characters to 3000. The user will not be able to enter more than that number of characters.

If you want to set the maximum number of characters using (Acrobat) JavaScript, you can do so. You would set the charLimit property of the field object, as in

```
this.getField("myField").charLimit = 3000 ;
```